# Contact Form 7 - Change background "on sent ok"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a form with a background image, I need when someone submits the form the image changes automatically.

What is the function to use in `on_sent_ok:`?

This is my form:

```
<div class="formfontana" style="background-image: url("XXX.jpg");"> 
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:50%;">
   <div style="width:100%; padding:5px; text-align:center;">[text* cognome class:accendifield placeholder "Il tuo cognome"]</div>
   <div style="width:100%; padding:5px; text-align:center;">[email* email class:accendifield placeholder "La tua email"]</div>
   <div style="width:100%; padding:5px; text-align:center; margin-top:20px;">[submit "Illumina la fontana di Trevi"]</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried something like:

```
on_sent_ok: "document.getElementById('DIV-ID').style.background-image = 'url("ZZZ.jpg")';
```

This is the solution:

`on_sent_ok: "document.getElementById('DIV-ID').style.backgroundImage = 'url(ZZZ.jpg)';"`

Thx to @rnevius

Comment: There is no function "on_sent_ok:". You can use ajax and from getting success function return you change it manually .

Comment: Can u help me please?

Comment: Post you code. How far you have tried.

Comment: This is my form: `<div class="formfontana" style="background-image: url("XXX.jpg");">
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:50%;">
<div style="width:100%; padding:5px; text-align:center;">[text* cognome class:accendifield placeholder "Il tuo cognome"]</div>
<div style="width:100%; padding:5px; text-align:center;">[email* email class:accendifield placeholder "La tua email"]</div>
<div style="width:100%; padding:5px; text-align:center; margin-top:20px;">[submit "Illumina la fontana di Trevi"]</div>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: I try with some like     `on_sent_ok: "document.getElementById('DIV-ID').style.background-image = 'url("ZZZ.jpg")';"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-image` is a CSS property. You should use `backgroundImage` in JavaScript. You should also omit the quotes around the url. In other words:

```
on_sent_ok: "document.getElementById('DIV-ID').style.backgroundImage = 'url(ZZZ.jpg)';"
```

Read more [at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference).

Answer (score 0):

You can call a custom JavaScript function when the form is successfully submitted. Just add your snippet to "additional settings" in the form.

```
on_sent_ok: "your_custom_function();"
```

http://contactform7.com/additional-settings/